# Check if String is a Partial Match to Another String

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray, mkmapview, uisearchbar

I have a search bar on my map view that allows the user to search for the name (annotation title) or address (annotation subtitle). I have it working just fine if the user types in the entire title or subtitle but I'm trying to have it so the user only has to type part of the name or address. For example, there is an annotation for Cates Farm. I'd like the user to be able to just type in cates and have it find the annotation. The way I have it set up not only just finds the last title in the array, but it runs slowly. Any help or suggestions?

Here is my code. The lines I've commented out are from where I had it working if the user types the entire title or subtitle.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    id<MKAnnotation> ann;
    NSString *searchText = [searchBar text];
    NSString *annTitle = ann.title;
    NSString *annSubtitle = ann.subtitle;
    NSRange titleRange = [annTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange subtitleRange = [annSubtitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    for (int i = 0; i < [marketLocations count]; i++)
    {
        for (ann in marketLocations)
        {
            // if ([ann.title isEqualToString:[searchBar text]])
            if (titleRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
            }
            // else if ([ann.subtitle isEqualToString:[searchBar text]])
            else if (subtitleRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

EDIT:

I'm now trying to implement the indexOfObjectPassingTest method to accomplish what I want but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it for my needs.

Here is all of the code for better context:

```
//
//  RSFM.m
//  KFBNewsroom

#import "RSFM.h"
#import "AnnotationDetailView.h"
#import "MapSettings.h"

@interface RSFM ()

@end

@implementation RSFM
{

}

@synthesize centerCoordinate, coordinate, title, subtitle, marketAnnotation, location, marketLocations;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self)
    {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Farm Markets", @"Farm Markets");
        // Create location manager object
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

        [locationManager setDelegate:self];

        // And we want it to be as accurate as possible regardless of how much time/power it takes
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers];

        // Tell our manager to start looking for its location immediately
        // [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)findLocation
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)foundLocation:(CLLocation *)loc
{
    // CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [loc coordinate];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2 = coordinate;
    coord2.latitude = 37.833333;
    coord2.longitude = -85.833333;

    // Zoom the region to this location
    // MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 400000, 400000);
    // MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 500, 500);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord2, 350000, 350000);
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    // Reset the UI
    // [locationTitleField setText:@""];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    // [locationTitleField setHidden:NO];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);

    // How many seconds ago was this new location created?
    NSTimeInterval t = [[newLocation timestamp]timeIntervalSinceNow];

    // CLLocationManagers will return the last found location of the device first, you don't want that data in this case.
    // If this location was made more than 3 minutes ago, ignore it.
    if (t < -180)
    {
        // this is cached data, you don't want it, keep looking
        return;
    }

    [self foundLocation:newLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // Tell the location manager to stop sending us messages
    [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
}

- (MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // If it's the user location, return nil
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    pinView.animatesDrop = NO;
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return pinView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    AnnotationDetailView *detail = [[AnnotationDetailView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    id<MKAnnotation> ann = [mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
    ann = view.annotation;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D annCoord;
    annCoord.latitude = ann.coordinate.latitude;
    annCoord.longitude = ann.coordinate.longitude;
    detail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    NSLog(@"%@", ann.title);
    NSLog(@"%@", ann.subtitle);
    detail.annTitle = ann.title;
    detail.annSub = ann.subtitle;
    detail.latText = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f",annCoord.latitude];
    detail.longText = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f", annCoord.longitude];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,44);
    searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = NO;
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];

    // NSMutableArray *marketLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    marketLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *lat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"37.7867266", @"37.0703517", @"37.1610806", @"37.318367", @"37.3559204", @"37.4154066", @"37.4757622", @"37.7450252", @"37.6318978", @"37.0716803", @"36.7333486", @"36.8637044", @"36.9181305", @"36.8736459", @"36.93253", @"37.0436832", @"37.1516087", @"36.712052", @"36.8082663", @"37.1799935", @"37.8928444", @"37.7488563", @"37.499522", @"37.5882222", @"37.4991846", @"37.5392879", @"37.3721288", @"37.1922315", @"37.102841", @"36.9813651", @"36.660251", @"37.1301316", @"37.1734765", @"37.0505279", @"36.9179492", @"37.2742692", @"37.2116415", @"37.2412938", @"37.2696374", @"37.5464147", @"37.5693561", @"37.7146149", @"37.7647463", @"37.635366", @"37.6417237", @"37.8515069", @"37.6840096", @"37.6000712", @"37.6655401", @"37.6668541", @"37.710869", @"37.7101039", @"37.8721419", @"37.9711379", @"38.0069215", @"38.135998", @"38.105713", @"38.160352", @"38.223825", @"38.188871", @"38.235703", @"38.3586935", @"38.3069755", @"38.6109009", @"38.3600355", @"38.4004693", @"38.5997367", @"38.6414842", @"38.5741722", @"38.1756649", @"38.2686626", @"38.4329612", @"38.673506", @"38.1916673", @"38.2265882", @"38.7363261", @"38.9734399", @"38.977975", @"38.8985392", @"38.903505", @"38.7418795", @"38.5102869", @"38.4260502", @"38.2687025", @"38.2097987", @"38.2074495", @"38.1356551", @"38.1245065", @"38.036634", @"37.9976315", @"37.7785109", @"37.9324058", @"37.9442351", @"37.9631701", @"37.9572905", @"38.0575357", @"37.8184352", @"37.920693", @"37.6256607", @"37.125056", @"37.911885", @"38.4948355", @"38.5124872", @"38.359333", @"37.5453841", @"36.7641572", @"37.5846472", nil];

    NSMutableArray *lon = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"-87.608209", @"-88.1237899", @"-87.9148629", @"-87.5074402", @"-87.5448032", @"-87.8003148", @"-87.9515986", @"-87.9061638", @"-87.1148574", @"-87.3008418", @"-87.5661605", @"-87.290597", @"-86.8270899", @"-86.6544847", @"-86.490067", @"-86.4558939", @"-86.2038694", @"-86.3287002", @"-85.9428197", @"-85.8312895", @"-86.2219159", @"-85.8042332", @"-85.8837926", @"-85.6896553", @"-85.6185338", @"-85.3974197", @"-85.3594512", @"-85.5906947", @"-85.3063504", @"-85.060269", @"-85.212777", @"-84.8720139", @"-84.8137247", @"-84.5698918", @"-84.1312625", @"-84.4614493", @"-84.4802606", @"-84.4223536", @"-84.6410206", @"-84.4564877", @"-84.2884479", @"-84.4089207", @"-84.3655048", @"-84.5597937", @"-84.7606165", @"-84.8732843", @"-85.2055835", @"-85.0401771", @"-85.248661", @"-85.1834814", @"-85.261238", @"-85.259706", @"-85.3155742", @"-85.689489", @"-85.8210816", @"-85.503977", @"-85.654787", @"-85.855705", @"-85.592095", @"-85.520966", @"-85.156767", @"-85.1048516", @"-85.1471807", @"-85.1186233", @"-85.5047839", @"-85.3788328", @"-85.3060421", @"-85.3237933", @"-85.2994716", @"-84.8965549", @"-84.6066196", @"-84.8581488", @"-84.8477954", @"-84.541101", @"-84.5685446", @"-84.6280011", @"-84.721179", @"-84.749313", @"-84.6090422", @"-84.441984", @"-84.0662604", @"-83.8971076", @"-83.8566679", @"-84.2433673", @"-84.2529869", @"-84.4785665", @"-84.3652534", @"-84.3541421", @"-84.551631", @"-84.7000274", @"-84.5389521", @"-84.3865064", @"-84.2261198", @"-84.2162117", @"-83.793939", @"-83.9017386", @"-84.0842092", @"-83.2513743", @"-83.5944371", @"-82.787241", @"-82.748201", @"-82.8310584", @"-82.7304443", @"-83.5611122", @"-84.3922468", @"-86.8666113",@"-87.2933751", nil];

    NSMutableArray *title1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cates Farm", @"Broadbent B & B Foods", @"Cayce's Pumpkin Patch", @"Metcalfe Landscaping", @"Brumfield Farm Market", @"Dogwood Valley Farm", @"Country Fresh Meats & Farmers Market", @"Jim David Meats", @"Trunnell's Farm Market", @"Lovell's Orchard & Farm Market", @"Zook's Produce", @"The Country Barn", @"Poore's Nursery & Farms", @"Just Piddlin Farm", @"Chaney's Dairy Barn & Restaurant", @"Jackson's Orchard & Nursery, Inc.", @"Mammoth Cave Transplants", @"Habegger's Amish Market", @"Kenny's Farmhouse Cheese", @"Dennison's Roadside Market", @"Roberts Family Farm", @"Wooden Farm", @"Jordan Greenhouses", @"Lee's Garden Center, Florist & Gift Shop", @"Hinton's Orchard & Farm Market", @"Serenity Farm Alpacas", @"Burton's Nursery & Garden Center", @"Davis Family Farms", @"Heavenly Haven Farm", @"French Valley Farms", @"Cravens Greenhouse", @"Haney's Appledale Farm", @"Hettmansperger's Greenhouse", @"D & F Farms", @"Double Hart Farm", @"Owens Garden Center", @"Hail's Farm", @"Sinking Valley Vineyard & Winery, Inc.", @"Todd's Greenhouse & Florist, LLC", @"McQuerry's Family Farm-Herbs-N-Heirlooms", @"Berea College Farm & Gardens", @"Acres of Land Winery & Restaurant", @"Baldwin Farms", @"Wonder of Life Farm", @"Chateau du Vieux Corbeau Winery/Old Crow Farm Winery", @"Devine's Farm & Corn Maze", @"Flaggy Meadow Fiber Works & Sunshine Alpacas of Kentucky", @"Williams Country Market", @"Serano Alpacas & Yarns", @"1851 Historic Maple Hill Manor B & B, Alpaca & Llama Farm, & Fiber Farm Store", @"Campbell Farm Wool Art Center", @"St. Catharine Farm", @"Capture Your Heart Alpacas", @"Ridgeview Greenhouse & Nursery", @"Country Corner Greenhouse & Nursery, Inc", @"Sunny Acres Farm", @"Morrison's Greenhouses", @"George Gagel Farm Market, LLC", @"Thieneman's Herbs & Perennials", @"Tower View Farm & Nursery", @"Gallrein Farms", @"Sweet Home Spun in the Low Dutch Meetinghouse", @"Mulberry Orchard, LLC", @"Gregory Farms", @"Foxhollow Farm Store", @"Sherwood Acres Beef", @"Bray Orchard & Roadside Market", @"Callis Orchards", @"Bray Fruit", @"Wilson's Nursery", @"Triple J Farm", @"Ayres Family Orchard", @"Michels Family Farm", @"Amerson Farm", @"Bi-Water Farm & Greenhouse", @"Alpine Hills Dairy Tour/Country Pumpkins", @"Blue Ribbon Market", @"Eagle Bend Alpacas Fiber & Gift Shoppe", @"Benton Farms", @"Redman's Farm",@"The Greenhouse in Gertrude", @"Croppers Greenhouse & Nursery", @"McLean's Aerofresh Fruit", @"Julie's Pumpkins", @"Reed Valley Orchard", @"Evans Orchard & Cider Mill", @"Kentucky Green Market", @"Antioch Daylily Garden", @"Golden Apple Fruit Market", @"Boyd Orchards", @"Serenity Hill Fiber & Living History Farm", @"Kelley Farms", @"Beech Springs Farm Market", @"Yuletide Tree Farm & Nursery", @"Townsend's Sorghum Mill and Farm Market", @"Bramble Ridge Orchard", @"C2H2 Farm Market", @"Fannin's Vegetables", @"Country Garden Greenhouse", @"Golden Apple Fruit Market", @"Black Barn Produce, LLC", @"Imel's Greenhouse", @"Feathered Wing Farm Market", @"Hutton-Loyd Tree Farm", @"Halcomb's Knob, LLC", @"Martin Farms", @"Happy Hollow Farms",nil];

    NSMutableArray *subtitle1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hwy 425 Henderson, KY 42420", @"257 Mary Blue Road Kuttawa, KY 42055", @"153 Farmersville Road Princeton, KY 42445", @"410 Princeton Road Madisonville, KY 42431", @"3320 Nebo Road Madisonville, KY 42431", @"4551 State Route 109N Clay, KY 42404", @"9355 US Hwy 60 W Sturgis, KY 42459",@"350 T. Frank Wathen Rd. Uniontown, KY 42461", @"9255 Hwy 431 Utica, KY 42376", @"22850 Coal Creek Road Hopkinsville, KY 42240", @"Intersection of KY107 & KY117 Herndon, KY  42240", @"112 Britmart Road Elkton, KY 42220", @"5486 Morgantown Road   Russellville, KY 42276", @"10830 S. Morgantown Rd.  Woodburn, KY 42170", @"9191 Nashville Road, Bowling Green, KY 42101", @"1280 Slim Island Road   Bowling Green, KY 42101", @"5394 Brownsville Road Brownsville, KY 42210", @"945 Perrytown Road  Scottsville, KY 42164", @"2033 Thomerson Park Road Austin, KY 42123", @"5824 S. Jackson Hwy. Horse Cave, KY 42749", @"125 Kennedy Road Guston, KY   40142", @"1869 Wooden Lane Elizabethtown, KY 42701", @"13287 Dixie Highway Upton, KY 42784", @"1918 Bardstown Road Hodgenville, KY 42748", @"8631 Campbellsville Road Hodgenville, KY 42748", @"1380 Frogg Lane Raywick, KY 40060", @"2212 Saloma Road Campbellsville, KY 42718", @"313 Hwy 1464 Greensburg, KY 42743", @"230 Heavenly Lane Columbia, KY 42728", @"1842 N. Main St. Jamestown, KY 42629", @"500 Cedar Hill Road Albany, KY 42602", @"8350 West 80 Nancy, KY 42544-8756", @"3917 N. Hwy 837 Science Hill, KY 42553", @"755 Elihu Rush Branch Road Somerset, KY 42501", @"6550 Cumberland Falls Road Corbin, KY 40701", @"735 Latham Road Somerset, KY 42503", @"Hwy 461, at 3 mile marker Somerset, KY 42503", @"1300 Plato-Vanhook Road Somerset, KY 42503", @"35 Skyline Drive Eubank, KY 42567", @"169 Pine Hill Road Paint Lick, KY 40461", @"230 N. Main St. Berea, KY 40404", @"2285 Barnes Mill Road Richmond, KY 40475", @"1113 Tates Creek Road Richmond, KY 40475", @"686 Buckeye Road Lancaster, KY 40444", @"471 Stanford Avenue Danville, KY 40422-1927", @"623 Talmage-Mayo Road Harrodsburg, KY 40330", @"2110 Mackville Road Springfield, KY 40069", @"4189 Craintown Rd. Gravel Switch, KY 40328", @"1805 Booker Road Springfield, KY 40069", @"2941 Perryville Road, US 150 Springfield, KY 40069", @"2888 Bardstown Road Springfield, KY 40069", @"2645 Bardstown Road Springfield, KY 40061", @"9430 Bloomfield Road Bloomfield, KY 40008", @"460 Buffalo Run Road Shepherdsville, KY 40165", @"4877 Hwy 44E Shepherdsville, KY 40165", @"6516 Echo Trail Jeffersontown, KY 40299", @"5613 Cooper Chapel Road Louisville, KY 40229", @"2400 Lower Hunters Trace Louisville, KY 40216", @"9120 Blowing Tree Road Louisville, KY 40220", @"12523 Taylorsville Road Jeffersontown, KY 40299", @"1029 Vigo Road Shelbyville, KY 40065", @"6805 Castle Hwy. Pleasureville, KY 40057", @"1330 Mulberry Pike Shelbyville, KY 40065", @"985 Vance Road Turners Station, KY 40075", @"8905 Hwy 329 Crestwood, KY 40014", @"215 Parker Drive LaGrange, KY 40031", @"2580 Hwy 42 W. Bedford, KY 40006", @"3721 Hwy 421 N Bedford, KY 40006", @"1660 Highway 421 N Bedford, KY 40006", @"3690 East-West Connector (Rte 676) Frankfort, KY 40601", @"2287 Long Lick Road Georgetown, KY 40324", @"525 Wilson Lane Owenton, KY 40359", @"4275 Hwy 1316 Sparta, KY 41086", @"130 McClelland Circle Georgetown, KY 40324", @"877 Cincinnati Road Georgetown, KY 40324", @"2165 Sherman Mount Zion Rd. Dry Ridge, KY 41035", @"8707 Camp Ernst Road Union, KY 41091", @"7812 East Bend Road Burlington, KY 41005", @"11896 Old Lexington Pike Walton, KY 41094", @"12449 Decoursey Pike Morning View, KY 41063", @"3246 Augusta-Berlin Road Brooksville, KY 41004", @"5350 Raymond Road May's Lick, KY 41055", @"4085 Ewing Road Ewing, KY 41039", @"1069 Ruddles Mill Road Paris, KY 40361", @"239 Lail Lane Paris, KY 40361", @"180 Stone Road Georgetown, KY 40324", @"5751 Lexington Rd. Lexington, KY 40511", @"2231 Houston Antioch Road Lexington, KY 40516", @"1801 Alexandria Drive Lexington, KY 40504", @"1396 Pinckard Pike Versailles, KY 40383", @"1371 Beverly Lane Nicholasville, KY 40356", @"6483 Old Richmond Road Lexington, KY 40515", @"4776 Old Boonesboro Road Winchester, KY 40391", @"3925 Old Boonesboro Road Winchester, KY 40391", @"11620 Main Street Jeffersonville, KY 40337", @"2726 Osborne Road Mt. Sterling, KY 40353", @"1098 Harris Ferry Road Irvine, KY 40336", @"2140 Hwy 460W West Liberty, KY 41472", @"99 Union Road Beattyville, KY 41311", @"1523 Hwy 119 North Whitesburg, KY 41815", @"52 KY Route 3224 River, KY 41254", @"2836 State Route 1 Greenup, KY 41144", @"45 Katherine Lane Greenup, KY 41144", @"1483 Big Run Road Wallingford, KY 41093", @"430 Wallacetown Road Paint Lick, KY 40461", @"5595 Nashville Road Russellville, KY 42276", @"9730 KY 136W Calhoun, KY 42327", nil];

    NSLog(@" Lat Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[lat count]);
    NSLog(@" Long Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[lon count]);
    NSLog(@" Title Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[title1 count]);
    NSLog(@" Subtitle Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[subtitle1 count]);

    // CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    // MKPointAnnotation *marketAnnotation;

    for (int x = 0; x < [lat count]; x++)
    {
        marketAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        location.latitude = [[lat objectAtIndex:x]floatValue];
        location.longitude = [[lon objectAtIndex:x]floatValue];
        marketAnnotation.coordinate = location;
        marketAnnotation.title = [title1 objectAtIndex:x];
        marketAnnotation.subtitle = [subtitle1 objectAtIndex:x];
        [marketLocations addObject:marketAnnotation];
    }

    [worldView addAnnotations:marketLocations];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSLog(@"searchBarTextDidEndEditing:");

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    id<MKAnnotation> ann;
    NSString *searchText = [searchBar text];
    NSString *annTitle = ann.title;
    NSString *annSubtitle = ann.subtitle;
    // NSString *marketTitle = marketAnnotation.title;
    // NSString *marketSubtitle = marketAnnotation.subtitle;
    // NSRange titleRange = [marketTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    // NSRange subtitleRange = [marketSubtitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange titleRange = [annTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange subtitleRange = [annSubtitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    for (int i = 0; i < [marketLocations count]; i++)
    {
        for (ann in marketLocations)
        {
            // if ([ann.title isEqualToString:[searchBar text]])
            if (titleRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
            }
            // else if ([ann.subtitle isEqualToString:[searchBar text]])
            else if (subtitleRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2 = coordinate;
    coord2.latitude = 37.833333;
    coord2.longitude = -85.833333;

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord2, 350000, 350000);
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.delegate = nil;
}

- (IBAction)selectSegmentControl
{
    int segmentTouched = [mapVarieties selectedSegmentIndex];
    NSString *segmentName = [mapVarieties titleForSegmentAtIndex:segmentTouched];
    if ([segmentName isEqualToString:@"Street"])
    {
        [worldView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    }
    if ([segmentName isEqualToString:@"Satellite"])
    {
        [worldView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
    }
    if ([segmentName isEqualToString:@"Hybrid"])
    {
        [worldView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're finding the range (i.e position) of the searchText within the annTitle which is built from the ann objet which is built from....nothing (line 1 of your function).

Move the `rangeOfString` lines into the loop so that you are checking for searchText within each `ann` that is is in your `marketLocations`

Comment: I tried moving those two lines into the loop and it still isn't performing correctly.  It always ends up showing the last annotation in my array, even if I search for something I know won't be found.

Comment: When you moved it inside the loop, did you move just the lines with `rangeOfString`? those lines use annTitle and annSubtitle. If you didn't also move the lines that calculate annTitle and annSubtitle then you'd have exactly the same values every time.